# R data.table concat arbitrary number of columns

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to concat an arbitrary number of columns of characters. using data table. This is easily done using `paste0` as shown in the following example.

```
library(data.table)

aa <- data.table(A=letters[1:5],B=LETTERS[1:5])

aa[,C:=paste0(A,B)]

#> aa
#A B  C
#1: a A aA
#2: b B bB
#3: c C cC
#4: d D dD
#5: e E eE
```

How can this be generalize to an arbitrary number of columns? I tried the follow but it does not work as expected

```
aa[,C:=apply(.SD,1,cat),.SDcols=1:2]
```

Comment: `aa[, do.call(paste0, .SD), .SDcols = my_cols]`, I guess.

Comment: Thanks it seems to work. `aa[, C:=do.call(paste0, .SD), .SDcols = 1:2]`. I'm keeping the question though as I it might be easier to find.